# Making a voxel engine

Tags: java, opengl

I've decided a while ago to make my own voxel engine. To start, I coded my own basic 3D engine in Java using minimal OpenGL bindings for things such as SRGB ect. I set up my own VBA and VBOS and had it working with .obj files. I already have transformations and Quaternions set up.

I've recently started to implement my attempt at a voxel engine. Last night I set up a very crude jury-rigged attempt that actually worked well enough with perlin noise to draw random 1x1x1 blocks on the screen that resembled a world.

The issue is that I've used immediate mode and block-by block-rendering with no chunks. So today I've decided to start writing my chunk class, and was hoping someone could tell me if it seems correctly set up.

Edit: I forgot to mention that I currently am trying to figure out how to handle vertices, so that's why there is no code.

```
package cam.base.engine;

public class Chunk
{
    public static final int X_CHUNK_SIZE = 16;
    public static final int Y_CHUNK_SIZE = 128;
    public static final int Z_CHUNK_SIZE = 16;

    public int chunkXNumber;
    public int chunkZNumber;

    private Block [][][] blocks = new Block[X_CHUNK_SIZE][Y_CHUNK_SIZE][Z_CHUNK_SIZE];

    public Chunk(int chunkXNumber, int chunkZNumber)
    {
        this.chunkXNumber = chunkXNumber;
        this.chunkZNumber = chunkZNumber;

        createBlocks(chunkXNumber, chunkZNumber);

        Vertex [][][] vertices = createVertices(getActiveBlocks(), chunkXNumber, chunkZNumber);
        int[] = createIndices(vertices);

    }

    private void createBlocks(int chunkXNum, int chunkZNum)
    {
        for(int i = 1; i <= X_CHUNK_SIZE; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 1; j <= Y_CHUNK_SIZE; j++)
            {
                for(int k = 1; k <= Z_CHUNK_SIZE; k++)
                {
                    float density = getDensity(new Vector3(i,j,k), chunkXNum, chunkZNum);
                    byte material = getMaterial(density,j);
                    boolean isActive = checkBlockActive(material);

                    blocks[i - 1][j - 1][k - 1] = new Block(material, isActive);
                }
            }
        }   
    }   

    private boolean[][][] getActiveBlocks()
    {
        boolean [][][] activeBlocks = new boolean[X_CHUNK_SIZE][Y_CHUNK_SIZE][Z_CHUNK_SIZE];

        for(int i = 0; i < X_CHUNK_SIZE; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < Y_CHUNK_SIZE; j++)
            {
                for(int k = 0; k < Z_CHUNK_SIZE; k++)
                {
                    activeBlocks[i][j][k] = blocks[i][j][k].isBlockEnabled();
                }   
            }   
        }   

        return activeBlocks;
    }

    private float getDensity(Vector3 chunkPos, int chunkXNum, int chunkZNum)
    {
        float density = 0;
        int x = chunkPos.getX() * chunkXNum;
        int y = chunkPos.getY() * chunkZNum;
        int z = chunkPos.getZ() * chunkZNum;

        //TODO check to see if double is necessary
        for(double i = 1; i <= Game.octaveLimit; i *= 2)
        {
            density += (1/i) * (Noise.noise((x / 160.0f) * i, (y / 160.0f) * i,( z / 160.0f) * i));
            density = Math.abs(density);
        }

        return density;
    }

    private byte getMaterial(float density, int yVal)
    {   
        byte material;

        if(density > .2)
        {
            if(yVal >= 80)
            {
                material = 0;
            }

            else
            {
                material = 1;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            if(yVal >= 64)
            {
                material = 0;
            }

            else
            {
                material = 2;
            }
        }
        return material;
    }

    private boolean checkBlockActive(byte material)
    {
        if(material == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    private Vertex[][][] createVertices(boolean[][][] activeBlocks, int chunkXNum, int chunkZNum)
    {
        boolean[][][] verticesActive = new boolean[X_CHUNK_SIZE][Y_CHUNK_SIZE][Z_CHUNK_SIZE];
        Vertex[][][] vertices = new Vertex[X_CHUNK_SIZE][Y_CHUNK_SIZE][Z_CHUNK_SIZE];

        for(int i = 1; i <= X_CHUNK_SIZE; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 1; j <= Y_CHUNK_SIZE; j++)
            {
                for(int k = 1; k <= Z_CHUNK_SIZE; k++)
                {
                    if(activeBlocks[i - 1][j - 1][k - 1])
                    {
                        if(verticesActive[i - 1][j - 1][k - 1] == false)
                        {
                            vertices[i - 1][j - 1][k - 1] = new Vertex(new Vector3(i * chunkXNum, j , k * chunkZNum));
                        }

                        continue;
                    }

                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

        return vertices;
    }

    private int[] createIndices(Vertex[][][] vertices)
    {




    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `createBlocks` actually fills the blocks array, creation happens before that, so this name is a little bit misleading. I'd move the array creation inside the method and use it as a return value:

   ```
   private Block[][][] blocks;

   public Chunk(int chunkXNumber, int chunkZNumber) {
       ..
       blocks = createBlocks(chunkXNumber, chunkZNumber);
   }

   private Block[][][] createBlocks(int chunkXNum, int chunkZNum) {
       final Block[][][] blocks = new Block[X_CHUNK_SIZE][Y_CHUNK_SIZE][Z_CHUNK_SIZE];
       // loops here
       return blocks;
   }
   ```
2. ```
   private boolean checkBlockActive(byte material) {
       if (material == 0) {
           return false;
       }

       else {
           return true;
       }
   }
   ```

   It could be simply

   ```
   private boolean checkBlockActive(byte material) {
       return material != 0;
   }
   ```
3. In the `getMaterial` method you could use multiple returns and get rid of the `result` variable:

   ```
   private byte getMaterial(final float density, final int yVal) {
       if (density > .2) {
           if (yVal >= 80) {
               return 0;
           } else {
               return 1;
           }
       } else {
           if (yVal >= 64) {
               return 0;
           } else {
               return 2;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. `160.0f` is used multiple times and it's a magic number. It would deserve a named constant.
5. The code should follow the [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html).
6. Some of the loops runs from `1` to `<= X_CHUNK_SIZE`, some of them `0` to `< X_CHUNK_SIZE`. It should be consistent.
7. The two continue is unnecessary here:

   ```
   for (int k = 1; k <= Z_CHUNK_SIZE; k++) {
       if (activeBlocks[i - 1][j - 1][k - 1]) {
           if (verticesActive[i - 1][j - 1][k - 1] == false) {
               vertices[i - 1][j - 1][k - 1] = new Vertex(new Vector3(i * chunkXNum, j, k * chunkZNum));
           }
           continue;
       }
       continue;
   }
   ```

Comment: Hahaha thanks for the reply. I actually made this a while ago and have since become less bad. My entire engine is in c++ now and actually lets you choose between using a Sparsevoxel octree, linear memory or hashing. Looking back a lot of the crap I was doing was bad :(.                                       Here's a couple semi recent pics.http://imgur.com/JWkX6Va,MXj3mN8,9miaW8Z

Comment: @RylandGoldstein: Nice pictures, thanks! :)